# MCMC - Maximum likelihood position not agreeing with posterior

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo

I have a bit of a weird one.

I have a model that I'm trying to fit to data (it's a model of the shape of a supernova lightcurve). I'm doing this using MCMC (specifically python's emcee package). My priors are all bounded and uniform, my likelihood is just the reduced chi squared. I run with 100 walkers, a burn-phase of 100, and a run-phase of 500.

After it's finished running, I pick roughly 1000 points in the chain at random and plot the model with these points alongside the data (The coloured lines in the below plot). Additionally, I find the parameter in the chain with the maximum likelihood (in this case, which has a reduced chi squared closest to 1) - (The black line in the plot).

Plot -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IEbp.jpg

As you can see the fit isn't terrible (at the very least it looks like its fitting roughly the right shape). The weirdness comes when I tried to plot the posterior's in a corner plot and include this maximum likelihood point.

Plot -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9arr.png

Here the black dashed line is the black line in the first plot. If you look at 2, the maximum likelihood is outside the 1 sigma bounds. If you look at the 3 the maximum likelihood is offset from the peak of the posterior. This seems wrong to me, I've no idea why this happens and I don't really know how to deal with it.

Any ideas of something I've gotten wrong?

Comment: The modes of the marginal posteriors do not have to coincide with the mode of the joint posterior, which may be the MLE in your case.